# Transform a non callable function into a callable function

Tags: python, function, callable, catboost

To explain: I use optuna on 5 classifier who are store in a dictionary.

To select one model, I use this:

```
 models={"CatBoostClassifier":CatBoostClassifier,"DecisionTreeClassifier":DecisionTreeClassifier....}
 for i in range(len(list(models))):
        model=list(models.values())[i]
        name=list(models.keys())[i]
```

After using optuna, I would like, for example, to transform `CatBoostClassifier()` into a callable function in order to write something like that:

```
    sampler = TPESampler(seed=1)
        study = optuna.create_study(study_name=model, direction="maximize", sampler=sampler)
        study.optimize(objective, n_trials=100)

        trial = study.best_trial

        model = model(**trial.params, verbose=False)
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

How could I do?? This make me an callable error:

```
    model = model(**trial.params, verbose=False)
    TypeError: 'CatBoostClassifier' object is not callable
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: all functions are callable, there are no "non-callable functions". If your object is not callable, then it is not a function.

Comment: It *seems* (you haven't really provided a [mcve] or a good error message) that the error comes from this line: `model = catt(**trial.params, verbose=False)`. Why are you trying to call `catt`? Why do you *think* it should be callable?

Comment: [here is an example from the docs of the library I assume you are using](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/python-quickstart)... did you *try looking at the documentation for how this class is supposed to be used*?

Comment: Please show your import statements.  E.g. (I'm guessing): `from catboost import CatBoostClassifier`

Comment: If you did `models={"CatBoostClassifier":CatBoostClassifier,"DecisionTreeClassifier":DecisionTreeClassifier....}` and `model=list(models.values())[i]`, then `model = model(**trial.params, verbose=False)` would **not** throw that error. What you rpobably actually did is `models={"CatBoostClassifier":CatBoostClassifier(), ...}`, so instead you should just do what you actually wrote above (and also iterate over the dictionary items using `for name, model in models.items(): ...` instead of what you are doing)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to programmatically build classifier models with parameter values from a dictionary called `trial.params`.  Am I right?

In which case, does this work?

```
for name, model_class in models.items():

    ...

    model = model_class(**trial.params, verbose=False)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)

    ...
```

When you execute `CatBoostClassifier()` it returns an instance of the class, which you then tried to call. I think what you wanted was the class itself which is `CatBoostClassifier`.

Comment: but **why on earth would you do this: `catt = CatBoostClassifier`**? why not just `model = CatBoostClassifier(**trial.params, verbose=False)`???

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am not sure why the OP does this.  Perhaps this is a simplified version of their actual code. For example the value of `catt` may change at each iteration of a loop that is not shown here.

Comment: I suspect this is just going to confuse them more.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga.  Okay.  In that case I will delete this answer.  Let's see what the OP says.

Comment: I updated the answer after OP changed the code in the question.